# Best technique for DHTML windows/dialogs in Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dhtml

I love [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api) but it doesn't come with any widgets. In particular, it provides nothing for window/dialog creation.

I've tried the [Prototype Window](http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/) add-on library but found it unreliable and it hasn't been maintained for a long time.

Anyone have any recommended solutions? Or any recipes/patterns for creating a dialog from first principles (i.e. with no library other than Prototype)? I need modal behavior (with faded background effect) and I have to support IE6 as well as modern browsers.

Just to be clear, I'm not looking to switch away from Prototype and I don't really want to include an additional base library such as JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a really simple dialog, checkout this code: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3411

Very minimal and simple - just what I wanted.

The code went through a few modifications. Here's the final version that worked for me:

```
/* 
 * Adapted from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3411
 */

var Dialog = {};
Dialog.Box = Class.create();
Object.extend(Dialog.Box.prototype, {
  initialize: function(id) {
    this.createOverlay();

    this.dialog_box = $(id);
    this.dialog_box.show = this.show.bind(this);
    this.dialog_box.persistent_show = this.persistent_show.bind(this);
    this.dialog_box.hide = this.hide.bind(this);

    this.parent_element = this.dialog_box.parentNode;

    this.dialog_box.style.position = "absolute";

    var e_dims = Element.getDimensions(this.dialog_box);
    var b_dims = Element.getDimensions(this.overlay);

    this.dialog_box.style.left = ((b_dims.width/2) - (e_dims.width/2)) + 'px';
    this.dialog_box.style.top = this.getScrollTop() + ((this.winHeight() - (e_dims.width/2))/2) + 'px';
    this.dialog_box.style.zIndex = this.overlay.style.zIndex + 1;
  },

  createOverlay: function() {
    if ($('dialog_overlay')) {
      this.overlay = $('dialog_overlay');
    } else {
      this.overlay = document.createElement('div');
      this.overlay.id = 'dialog_overlay';
      Object.extend(this.overlay.style, {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 90,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        display: 'none'
      });
      document.body.insertBefore(this.overlay, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    }
  },

  moveDialogBox: function(where) {
    Element.remove(this.dialog_box);
    if (where == 'back')
      this.dialog_box = this.parent_element.appendChild(this.dialog_box);
    else
      this.dialog_box = this.overlay.parentNode.insertBefore(this.dialog_box, this.overlay);
  },

  show: function(optHeight/* optionally override the derived height, which often seems to be short. */) {
    this.overlay.style.height = this.winHeight()+'px';
    this.moveDialogBox('out');

    this.overlay.onclick = this.hide.bind(this);

    this.selectBoxes('hide');
    new Effect.Appear(this.overlay, {duration: 0.1, from: 0.0, to: 0.3});
    this.dialog_box.style.display = '';

    this.dialog_box.style.left = '0px';

    var e_dims = Element.getDimensions(this.dialog_box);

    this.dialog_box.style.left = (this.winWidth() - e_dims.width)/2 + 'px';

    var h = optHeight || (e_dims.height + 200);
    this.dialog_box.style.top = this.getScrollTop() + (this.winHeight() - h/2)/2 + 'px';
  },

  getScrollTop: function() {
    return (window.pageYOffset)?window.pageYOffset:(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)?document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.body.scrollTop;
  },

  persistent_show: function() {
    this.overlay.style.height = this.winHeight()+'px';
    this.moveDialogBox('out');

    this.selectBoxes('hide');
    new Effect.Appear(this.overlay, {duration: 0.1, from: 0.0, to: 0.3});

    this.dialog_box.style.display = '';
    this.dialog_box.style.left = '0px';
    var e_dims = Element.getDimensions(this.dialog_box);
    this.dialog_box.style.left = (this.winWidth()/2 - e_dims.width/2) + 'px';
  },

  hide: function() {
    this.selectBoxes('show');
    new Effect.Fade(this.overlay, {duration: 0.1});
    this.dialog_box.style.display = 'none';
    this.moveDialogBox('back');
    $A(this.dialog_box.getElementsByTagName('input')).each( function(e) {
      if (e.type != 'submit' && e.type != 'button') e.value = '';
    });
  },

  selectBoxes: function(what) {
    $A(document.getElementsByTagName('select')).each(function(select) {
      Element[what](select);
    });

    if (what == 'hide')
      $A(this.dialog_box.getElementsByTagName('select')).each(function(select){Element.show(select)})
  },

  winWidth: function() {
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
       return window.innerWidth;
    if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
       return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth
  },
  winHeight: function() {
    if (typeof window.innerHeight != 'undefined')
      return window.innerHeight
    if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined' && typeof document.documentElement.clientHeight != 'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientHeight != 0)
      return document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few good sites to look at:

[Prototype UI](http://prototype-ui.com/) - which has a modal dialog.

[Scripteka](http://scripteka.com/) - The mother lode of Prototype add-ons. Lots of great stuff here.

Comment: Thanks! Prototype UI's Window seems to share some heritage with the "Prototype Window" library I was already using. Users on its forum seem frustrated with bugs & slow performance in IE6. Scripteka, on the other hand, looks nice and simple, and the demos work great in IE6. 

Cheers,
David

Comment: Ah, after trying the Dialog code from Scripteka, it didn't work in my CSS layout (dialog offset way to the left), so no go. See my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) is a UI/Widget/effects library built on top of Prototype. You're bound to find what you're looking for there.

Comment: Actually, no - Scriptaculous is mostly about effects.